# Repeat Task before condition

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

Is there way to repeat `Task` before any condition without using timers?

I want load users from database in `Task` and repeat this `Task` before users actually loaded (might be connection problems).

May be it look like:

```
private Action _LoadUsers()
{
    if (0 == Users.Count)
    {
        _loadUsersTask = new Task(() => _LoadUsersFromDB).ContinueWith(_LoadUsers);
    }
    else
    {
        _loadUsersTask = null;
    }
}
```

but this code doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean: "before users actually loaded" or "UNTIL users actually loaded"?

Comment: @jberger: I mean "UNTIL". Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Where do you actually start `loadUsersTask`?  It looks like you're only creating it and not starting.